# Laravel: pass field to resolveRouteBinding from route definition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a seemingly stupid question here but I can't find how one is supposed to define explicit model binding resolution logic using `resolveRouteBinding` method on a Model.

I managed to write down its logic which is based on the value of the `field` parameter but I can't seem to work out how to pass a value to this parameter when I define the route.

Can anyone please help me out?

**EDIT:** The proper question is how to tell the framework what value to pass to the `field` parameter?

**EDIT 2:** Here's an example of what I'm doing without luck.

Basically I want to implement a custom logic to retrieve a class representing a many-to-many relationship.

These are the *master* classes.

```php
class Competition extends Model {
    // ...

    /**
     * Get the editions of the competition.
     */
    public function competitionSeasons() {
        return $this->hasMany(CompetitionSeason::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class Season extends Model {
    // ...

    /**
     * Get the editions of the competitions in this season
     */
    public function competitionsSeasons() {
        return $this->hasMany(CompetitionSeason::class);
    }
}
```

This is the relationship class.

```php
class CompetitionSeason extends Model {
    // ...

    /**
     * Get the competition of this competition edition.
     */
    public function competition() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Competition::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the season of this competition edition.
     */
    public function season() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Season::class);
    }

    public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null) {
        error_log("[resolveRouteBinding] Field: " . $field);

        // TODO: make the query
    }

    public function resolveChildRouteBinding($childType, $value, $field = null) {
        error_log("[resolveChildRouteBinding] Field: " . $field);

        // TODO: make the query
    }
}
```

What I want now is to have a CompetitionSeason injected in the controller as a nested resource under Season (and also under Competition later on).

So this is how the route has been defined.

```php
// api.php

Route::apiResource('seasons.competitionSeasons', MockController::class)->scoped([
    'competitionSeason' => 'competition'
]);
```

Since I'm using slugs on the routes rather than IDs, `competition` here would be needed in any of the `resolveBinding` methods to navigate the relationship and get the slug from the `Competition` instance.

Basically, the request would be like this:

```
GET .../api/seasons/19-20/competitionSeasons/premier-league
```

where `premier-league` is the slug of the referenced `Competition`, the other end of the many-to-many relationship basically.

This is the Controller.. completely useless for now.

```php
class MockController extends Controller {

    public function show(Season $season, CompetitionSeason $competitionSeason) {
        error_log($competitionSeason);
    }
}
```

I know how to implment the missing logic, I have it very clear, what I would like to see is the `$field` being printed when the framework attempts to resolve the required instance of `CompetitionSeason`  so that I can get the slug of the associated resource as well as to know which relationship to navigate when `CompetitionSeason`  will be a child resource of `Competition` too.

Comment: what have you tried so far? What are the errors you get with the code you made trying to solve your problem?

Comment: I've updated the question with relevant snippets of code I'm trying to use right now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out how it is supposed to work even though I don't know why it's like this.. (some considerations below).

Basically the `public function resolveChildRouteBinding` I should override is the **parent**, so `Season` in this case.

So now `Season` looks like this:

```php
class Season extends Model {
    // ...

    public function competitionsSeasons() {
        return $this->hasMany(CompetitionSeason::class);
    }


    public function resolveChildRouteBinding($childType, $value, $field = null) {
        error_log("[resolveChildRouteBinding] Field: " . $field);

        if ($childType == 'competitionSeason') {
            if ($field == 'competition' {
                // TODO: make the query
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here I can see `$field` being `competition` with `$value` equal to `premier-league`.

Now some considerations: **why should the parent class be the one that returns the instance of the child?**

Basically, if I go on and implement it like this, the `resolveChildRouteBinding` will be the one to return the `CompetitionSeason` while I would have expected the resolution logic on `CompetitionSeason` itself to be what determines the instance to inject. Am I the only one?

Thank you to @lagbox for pointing out the existence of `resolveChildRouteBinding` which I completely ignored for whatever reason (maybe deserves a little more space in the docs?)

Answer (score 1):

That would be when you customize the key used for Implicit Route Model Binding via the route definition:

```
Route::get('users/{user:name}', ...);
```

`'name'` would end up being passed as the `$field` to that method call.

From `Illuminte\Database\Eloquent\Model`:

```
public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
{
    return $this->resolveRouteBindingQuery($this, $value, $field)->first();
}

public function resolveRouteBindingQuery($query, $value, $field = null)
{
    return $query->where($field ?? $this->getRouteKeyName(), $value);
}
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Routing - Route Model Binding - Implicit Bindings - Customizing the Key](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name)

**Update:**

If you need to create this custom binding with Resource Routing you can use the `scoped` method on the route definition:

```
Route::resource('users', Controller::class)
    ->scoped(['user' => 'name']);
```

You also could use the `$options` argument (3rd argument) on `resource` directly:

```
Route::resource('users', Controller::class, [
    'bindingFields' => [
        'user' => 'name'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Is there a way this could be achieved with ```Route::apiResource()```? I've been scratching my head around it for a while now..

Comment: @wileecoyote I updated the answer to show an example using resource routing

Comment: Thank you @lagbox. I made some tests and it works but not in the case where I need it, which is as a nested resource. I can't see the method being called.. Do you know if it's supposed to work like this by design?

Comment: @wileecoyote there are other methods that could be called instead of that one: `resolveSoftDeletableRouteBinding`, `resolveChildRouteBinding`, `resolveSoftDeletableChildRouteBinding`  ... if you have a nested resource this could be calling the 'child' methods (as it would be scoping)

Comment: Thank you once again, I've been trying a few configurations but still I can't manage to get any of the methods called. I simply tried the "standard" nested resource declaration and then I used the scoped version too, yet no sign of the method being called..

Comment: I've update the questio with relevant snippets of the code.. maybe it can help.

Comment: So I found out that `resolveChildRouteBinding` gets called on the parent model when it appears in a nested resource.. sadly in my case this is not helpful as what I would like to achieve is to make a custom logic on the child model based on the type of the parent :(